# How to add a new persistent store for CoreData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData and some data needs to be synced with iCloud and some don't. I did a bit of research and I found the solution is to [have separate persistent stores](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26879084/830098).

I am using some pre-generated code like below to use CoreData in the default way without problem:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("MyAppCoreData.sqlite")

    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

There is also a file in XCode `MyApp.xcdatamodeld` created by default where I can add/modify entities.

Now I want to add a new persistent store (say, store 2), here are my questions:

(1) I am planning to add the new persistent store like this:

```
try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url_2, options: option_2)
```

Anything else I need to add?

(2) If I want to add/modify entities for store 2, should I create a new `store2.xcdatamodeld` file? How can this file be linked with the actual code?

(3) When I want to access an entity, I do something like this:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ContentViewData")
// ... 
managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
```

How to do the same (e.g. execute some fetch request) for entities in store 2?

Maybe my understanding is not totally correct and some of my questions are not valid, please answer in your discretion.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest.you can configure 2 database in 1 xcdatamodeld file. then using configuration to switch persistent store

```
coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: configuration_1, URL: url, options: option)
```

[references](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/06/06/multiple-persistent-stores-in-core-data/)